# Problems with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am new to mathematica and I have doubts with my code, I probably have errors with the boundary conditions

If you could help me I would appreciate it very much
my code is the following

```
NDSolve[{\[Alpha]*(D[T[x, y, t], {x, 2}] +2.5*D[T[x, y, t], {y, 2}]) == D[T[x, y, t], {t, 1}], 
T[x, y, 0] == to, Derivative[1, 0, 0][T][0, y, t] == 0,Derivative[0, 1, 0][T][x, 0, t] == 0, -k*D[T[L, y, t], {x, 1}] ==h*(T[L, y, t] - tam), -2.5*k*D[T[x, L, t], {x, 1}] ==h*(T[x, L, t] - tam)}, T[x, y, t], {x, y, t}]
```

I was careful with the double problem =

Comment: The parameters `to, tam,h,k,L` must be defined, otherwise `NDSolve`won't work.

Comment: thanks it worked